# Python: Can a Decorator access argument from foo1() and supply it to foo2()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

More precisely

```
@string_supply #This should supply **string** from foo1 into foo2
def foo2(x):
    #Cannot use global string. string changes
    return list(itertools.compress(string, x)) # **string** needed here

def foo1(startrange, string):
    temp = None
    temp_list = map(temp, start_range_compute_list(startrange))
    ls_of = map(foo2, temp_list)
    yield ls_of
```

Can a @string_supply decorator be written like this? I am not experienced with decorators.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't. Decorator can't access internals of decorated functions. Maybe it's doable by some dirty hack, but IMHO it's better to avoid such solutions.

From architecture you've described — looks like you need class with instance variables. Something like:

```
class Simple(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._string = ""

    def foo2(self, x):
        #Cannot use global string. string changes
        return list(itertools.compress(self._string, x)) # **string** needed here

    def foo1(self, startrange, string):
        self._string = string
        temp = None
        temp_list = map(temp, start_range_compute_list(startrange))
        ls_of = map(foo2, temp_list)
        yield ls_of
```

Comment: hm ok good.so you mean encapsulation? i am clueless how to do that

Comment: I didn't completely got what you're trying to do, but I've added some simple example. If you'll describe the task in more details — I'll update it.

Comment: what is _string? is it a built in pvt attr? or you made a private method variable? so you mean this way whatever variable is in foo1(including its arg) here its string, it will be the same in foo2??? What I am trying to do is access some arg/var from a function in another function. I thought this could be done by defining two functions, 1 that accesses foo1 arg/var and 2nd function that passes them to foo2 under the same decorator.i dont know if that is possible

Comment: Yes, it's a class' private variable. And it's acessible from both methods. So, I think it's what you want. Read this tutorial about classes in Python http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html It's right what you need here.